# AngularJS - $compile doesn't working

Tags: angularjs, compilation

I'm trying to use the $compile in AngularJS.
I'm Read how to use $compile in [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile).
Wrote it in my app, after starting the see the error

My code:

```
@EnumeratorDirective = () ->
    restrict: 'A'
    scope:
        count: '@uiCount'

    link: (scope, element) ->
        scope.size = element.val().length

        element.bind 'keyup', () ->
            scope.size = element.val().length
            ngApply(scope)


        el = angular.element('<div class="enumerator">{{ size }} of {{ count }}</div>')
        $compile(el.contents())(scope)
        element.parent().append(el)
```

And it's output:

```
ReferenceError: $compile is not defined
at link (http://10.0.1.100:88/assets/js/app.js:697:9)
at i (http://10.0.1.100:88/assets/js/angular/angular.1.0.7.min.js:44:6)
at e (http://10.0.1.100:88/assets/js/angular/angular.1.0.7.min.js:39:307)
at http://10.0.1.100:88/assets/js/angular/angular.1.0.7.min.js:38:372
at http://10.0.1.100:88/assets/js/angular/angular.1.0.7.min.js:39:257
at new S.controller (http://10.0.1.100:88/assets/js/angular/angular.1.0.7.min.js:150:223)
at d (http://10.0.1.100:88/assets/js/angular/angular.1.0.7.min.js:28:174)
at Object.instantiate (http://10.0.1.100:88/assets/js/angular/angular.1.0.7.min.js:28:304)
at http://10.0.1.100:88/assets/js/angular/angular.1.0.7.min.js:52:239
at http://10.0.1.100:88/assets/js/angular/angular.1.0.7.min.js:43:348 <input enumerator="enumerator" ui-count="13" type="text" required="required" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope">
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject the `$compile` service into your directive.  You can read about dependecy injection in AngularJS [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).